# How to generate a Julian date from POSIXct within a 365 day period

Tags: r, date, posix, julian-date

I am trying to create a Julian date from a `POSIXct` date that is 1-365 for each 365 day period.

More specifically, with the dates below covering a 2 year period starting 2013-2-15, I have have used the `julian()` function to create a new Julian date.

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.POSIXct("2013-2-15"), by = "day", length.out = 730))
DF$Julian = 1+(as.numeric(julian(DF$Date, origin = as.POSIXct("2013-2-15"))))


        Date Julian
1 2013-02-15      1
2 2013-02-16      2
3 2013-02-17      3
4 2013-02-18      4
5 2013-02-19      5
6 2013-02-20      6


> tail(DF)
          Date Julian
725 2015-02-09    725
726 2015-02-10    726
727 2015-02-11    727
728 2015-02-12    728
729 2015-02-13    729
730 2015-02-14    730
```

However, as seen in the `tail()` above, the Julian date spans to 730, the entire 2 years.  I want the julian day to be scaled relative to start day (as is done here), but no greater than 365.  I want 15-Feb to be 1 and and Feb 14th or the following year is 365. In essence, the Julian day should start over at 1 for each 365 day period.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT/ADDITION**
If, for example I want to calculate the Julian date with a specific origin, I can use the following code:

```
DF$JulianNew <- as.integer(julian(DF$Date,origin=as.Date("2013-2-16")))%%365L+1L
```

However, as seen in the `head`

```
        Date Julian JulianNew
1 2013-02-15      1         1
2 2013-02-16      2         1
3 2013-02-17      3         2
4 2013-02-18      4         3
5 2013-02-19      5         4
6 2013-02-20      6         5
```

The date 2013-02-15 is marked as being within one day of the origin of 2013-02-16.  How can ensure that dates in the past are not included and that the search goes only forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
DF$Julian <- as.integer(julian(DF$Date,origin=DF$Date[1]))%%365L+1L;
DF;
##                    Date Julian
## 1   2013-02-15 00:00:00      1
## 2   2013-02-16 00:00:00      2
## 3   2013-02-17 00:00:00      3
## 4   2013-02-18 00:00:00      4
## 5   2013-02-19 00:00:00      5
## 6   2013-02-20 00:00:00      6
## 7   2013-02-21 00:00:00      7
## 8   2013-02-22 00:00:00      8
## 9   2013-02-23 00:00:00      9
## 10  2013-02-24 00:00:00     10
## 11  2013-02-25 00:00:00     11
## 12  2013-02-26 00:00:00     12
## 13  2013-02-27 00:00:00     13
## 14  2013-02-28 00:00:00     14
## 15  2013-03-01 00:00:00     15
## 16  2013-03-02 00:00:00     16
## 17  2013-03-03 00:00:00     17
## 18  2013-03-04 00:00:00     18
## 19  2013-03-05 00:00:00     19
## 20  2013-03-06 00:00:00     20
## 21  2013-03-07 00:00:00     21
## 22  2013-03-08 00:00:00     22
## 23  2013-03-09 00:00:00     23
## 24  2013-03-10 00:00:00     24
## 25  2013-03-11 01:00:00     25
## 26  2013-03-12 01:00:00     26
## 27  2013-03-13 01:00:00     27
## 28  2013-03-14 01:00:00     28
## 29  2013-03-15 01:00:00     29
## 30  2013-03-16 01:00:00     30
## 31  2013-03-17 01:00:00     31
## 32  2013-03-18 01:00:00     32
## 33  2013-03-19 01:00:00     33
## 34  2013-03-20 01:00:00     34
## 35  2013-03-21 01:00:00     35
## 36  2013-03-22 01:00:00     36
## 37  2013-03-23 01:00:00     37
## 38  2013-03-24 01:00:00     38
## 39  2013-03-25 01:00:00     39
## 40  2013-03-26 01:00:00     40
## 41  2013-03-27 01:00:00     41
## 42  2013-03-28 01:00:00     42
## 43  2013-03-29 01:00:00     43
## 44  2013-03-30 01:00:00     44
## 45  2013-03-31 01:00:00     45
## 46  2013-04-01 01:00:00     46
## 47  2013-04-02 01:00:00     47
## 48  2013-04-03 01:00:00     48
## 49  2013-04-04 01:00:00     49
## 50  2013-04-05 01:00:00     50
## 51  2013-04-06 01:00:00     51
## 52  2013-04-07 01:00:00     52
## 53  2013-04-08 01:00:00     53
## 54  2013-04-09 01:00:00     54
## 55  2013-04-10 01:00:00     55
## 56  2013-04-11 01:00:00     56
## 57  2013-04-12 01:00:00     57
## 58  2013-04-13 01:00:00     58
## 59  2013-04-14 01:00:00     59
## 60  2013-04-15 01:00:00     60
## 61  2013-04-16 01:00:00     61
## 62  2013-04-17 01:00:00     62
## 63  2013-04-18 01:00:00     63
## 64  2013-04-19 01:00:00     64
## 65  2013-04-20 01:00:00     65
## 66  2013-04-21 01:00:00     66
## 67  2013-04-22 01:00:00     67
## 68  2013-04-23 01:00:00     68
## 69  2013-04-24 01:00:00     69
## 70  2013-04-25 01:00:00     70
## 71  2013-04-26 01:00:00     71
## 72  2013-04-27 01:00:00     72
## 73  2013-04-28 01:00:00     73
## 74  2013-04-29 01:00:00     74
## 75  2013-04-30 01:00:00     75
## 76  2013-05-01 01:00:00     76
## 77  2013-05-02 01:00:00     77
## 78  2013-05-03 01:00:00     78
## 79  2013-05-04 01:00:00     79
## 80  2013-05-05 01:00:00     80
## 81  2013-05-06 01:00:00     81
## 82  2013-05-07 01:00:00     82
## 83  2013-05-08 01:00:00     83
## 84  2013-05-09 01:00:00     84
## 85  2013-05-10 01:00:00     85
## 86  2013-05-11 01:00:00     86
## 87  2013-05-12 01:00:00     87
## 88  2013-05-13 01:00:00     88
## 89  2013-05-14 01:00:00     89
## 90  2013-05-15 01:00:00     90
## 91  2013-05-16 01:00:00     91
## 92  2013-05-17 01:00:00     92
## 93  2013-05-18 01:00:00     93
## 94  2013-05-19 01:00:00     94
## 95  2013-05-20 01:00:00     95
## 96  2013-05-21 01:00:00     96
## 97  2013-05-22 01:00:00     97
## 98  2013-05-23 01:00:00     98
## 99  2013-05-24 01:00:00     99
## 100 2013-05-25 01:00:00    100
## 101 2013-05-26 01:00:00    101
## 102 2013-05-27 01:00:00    102
## 103 2013-05-28 01:00:00    103
## 104 2013-05-29 01:00:00    104
## 105 2013-05-30 01:00:00    105
## 106 2013-05-31 01:00:00    106
## 107 2013-06-01 01:00:00    107
## 108 2013-06-02 01:00:00    108
## 109 2013-06-03 01:00:00    109
## 110 2013-06-04 01:00:00    110
## 111 2013-06-05 01:00:00    111
## 112 2013-06-06 01:00:00    112
## 113 2013-06-07 01:00:00    113
## 114 2013-06-08 01:00:00    114
## 115 2013-06-09 01:00:00    115
## 116 2013-06-10 01:00:00    116
## 117 2013-06-11 01:00:00    117
## 118 2013-06-12 01:00:00    118
## 119 2013-06-13 01:00:00    119
## 120 2013-06-14 01:00:00    120
## 121 2013-06-15 01:00:00    121
## 122 2013-06-16 01:00:00    122
## 123 2013-06-17 01:00:00    123
## 124 2013-06-18 01:00:00    124
## 125 2013-06-19 01:00:00    125
## 126 2013-06-20 01:00:00    126
## 127 2013-06-21 01:00:00    127
## 128 2013-06-22 01:00:00    128
## 129 2013-06-23 01:00:00    129
## 130 2013-06-24 01:00:00    130
## 131 2013-06-25 01:00:00    131
## 132 2013-06-26 01:00:00    132
## 133 2013-06-27 01:00:00    133
## 134 2013-06-28 01:00:00    134
## 135 2013-06-29 01:00:00    135
## 136 2013-06-30 01:00:00    136
## 137 2013-07-01 01:00:00    137
## 138 2013-07-02 01:00:00    138
## 139 2013-07-03 01:00:00    139
## 140 2013-07-04 01:00:00    140
## 141 2013-07-05 01:00:00    141
## 142 2013-07-06 01:00:00    142
## 143 2013-07-07 01:00:00    143
## 144 2013-07-08 01:00:00    144
## 145 2013-07-09 01:00:00    145
## 146 2013-07-10 01:00:00    146
## 147 2013-07-11 01:00:00    147
## 148 2013-07-12 01:00:00    148
## 149 2013-07-13 01:00:00    149
## 150 2013-07-14 01:00:00    150
## 151 2013-07-15 01:00:00    151
## 152 2013-07-16 01:00:00    152
## 153 2013-07-17 01:00:00    153
## 154 2013-07-18 01:00:00    154
## 155 2013-07-19 01:00:00    155
## 156 2013-07-20 01:00:00    156
## 157 2013-07-21 01:00:00    157
## 158 2013-07-22 01:00:00    158
## 159 2013-07-23 01:00:00    159
## 160 2013-07-24 01:00:00    160
## 161 2013-07-25 01:00:00    161
## 162 2013-07-26 01:00:00    162
## 163 2013-07-27 01:00:00    163
## 164 2013-07-28 01:00:00    164
## 165 2013-07-29 01:00:00    165
## 166 2013-07-30 01:00:00    166
## 167 2013-07-31 01:00:00    167
## 168 2013-08-01 01:00:00    168
## 169 2013-08-02 01:00:00    169
## 170 2013-08-03 01:00:00    170
## 171 2013-08-04 01:00:00    171
## 172 2013-08-05 01:00:00    172
## 173 2013-08-06 01:00:00    173
## 174 2013-08-07 01:00:00    174
## 175 2013-08-08 01:00:00    175
## 176 2013-08-09 01:00:00    176
## 177 2013-08-10 01:00:00    177
## 178 2013-08-11 01:00:00    178
## 179 2013-08-12 01:00:00    179
## 180 2013-08-13 01:00:00    180
## 181 2013-08-14 01:00:00    181
## 182 2013-08-15 01:00:00    182
## 183 2013-08-16 01:00:00    183
## 184 2013-08-17 01:00:00    184
## 185 2013-08-18 01:00:00    185
## 186 2013-08-19 01:00:00    186
## 187 2013-08-20 01:00:00    187
## 188 2013-08-21 01:00:00    188
## 189 2013-08-22 01:00:00    189
## 190 2013-08-23 01:00:00    190
## 191 2013-08-24 01:00:00    191
## 192 2013-08-25 01:00:00    192
## 193 2013-08-26 01:00:00    193
## 194 2013-08-27 01:00:00    194
## 195 2013-08-28 01:00:00    195
## 196 2013-08-29 01:00:00    196
## 197 2013-08-30 01:00:00    197
## 198 2013-08-31 01:00:00    198
## 199 2013-09-01 01:00:00    199
## 200 2013-09-02 01:00:00    200
## 201 2013-09-03 01:00:00    201
## 202 2013-09-04 01:00:00    202
## 203 2013-09-05 01:00:00    203
## 204 2013-09-06 01:00:00    204
## 205 2013-09-07 01:00:00    205
## 206 2013-09-08 01:00:00    206
## 207 2013-09-09 01:00:00    207
## 208 2013-09-10 01:00:00    208
## 209 2013-09-11 01:00:00    209
## 210 2013-09-12 01:00:00    210
## 211 2013-09-13 01:00:00    211
## 212 2013-09-14 01:00:00    212
## 213 2013-09-15 01:00:00    213
## 214 2013-09-16 01:00:00    214
## 215 2013-09-17 01:00:00    215
## 216 2013-09-18 01:00:00    216
## 217 2013-09-19 01:00:00    217
## 218 2013-09-20 01:00:00    218
## 219 2013-09-21 01:00:00    219
## 220 2013-09-22 01:00:00    220
## 221 2013-09-23 01:00:00    221
## 222 2013-09-24 01:00:00    222
## 223 2013-09-25 01:00:00    223
## 224 2013-09-26 01:00:00    224
## 225 2013-09-27 01:00:00    225
## 226 2013-09-28 01:00:00    226
## 227 2013-09-29 01:00:00    227
## 228 2013-09-30 01:00:00    228
## 229 2013-10-01 01:00:00    229
## 230 2013-10-02 01:00:00    230
## 231 2013-10-03 01:00:00    231
## 232 2013-10-04 01:00:00    232
## 233 2013-10-05 01:00:00    233
## 234 2013-10-06 01:00:00    234
## 235 2013-10-07 01:00:00    235
## 236 2013-10-08 01:00:00    236
## 237 2013-10-09 01:00:00    237
## 238 2013-10-10 01:00:00    238
## 239 2013-10-11 01:00:00    239
## 240 2013-10-12 01:00:00    240
## 241 2013-10-13 01:00:00    241
## 242 2013-10-14 01:00:00    242
## 243 2013-10-15 01:00:00    243
## 244 2013-10-16 01:00:00    244
## 245 2013-10-17 01:00:00    245
## 246 2013-10-18 01:00:00    246
## 247 2013-10-19 01:00:00    247
## 248 2013-10-20 01:00:00    248
## 249 2013-10-21 01:00:00    249
## 250 2013-10-22 01:00:00    250
## 251 2013-10-23 01:00:00    251
## 252 2013-10-24 01:00:00    252
## 253 2013-10-25 01:00:00    253
## 254 2013-10-26 01:00:00    254
## 255 2013-10-27 01:00:00    255
## 256 2013-10-28 01:00:00    256
## 257 2013-10-29 01:00:00    257
## 258 2013-10-30 01:00:00    258
## 259 2013-10-31 01:00:00    259
## 260 2013-11-01 01:00:00    260
## 261 2013-11-02 01:00:00    261
## 262 2013-11-03 01:00:00    262
## 263 2013-11-04 00:00:00    263
## 264 2013-11-05 00:00:00    264
## 265 2013-11-06 00:00:00    265
## 266 2013-11-07 00:00:00    266
## 267 2013-11-08 00:00:00    267
## 268 2013-11-09 00:00:00    268
## 269 2013-11-10 00:00:00    269
## 270 2013-11-11 00:00:00    270
## 271 2013-11-12 00:00:00    271
## 272 2013-11-13 00:00:00    272
## 273 2013-11-14 00:00:00    273
## 274 2013-11-15 00:00:00    274
## 275 2013-11-16 00:00:00    275
## 276 2013-11-17 00:00:00    276
## 277 2013-11-18 00:00:00    277
## 278 2013-11-19 00:00:00    278
## 279 2013-11-20 00:00:00    279
## 280 2013-11-21 00:00:00    280
## 281 2013-11-22 00:00:00    281
## 282 2013-11-23 00:00:00    282
## 283 2013-11-24 00:00:00    283
## 284 2013-11-25 00:00:00    284
## 285 2013-11-26 00:00:00    285
## 286 2013-11-27 00:00:00    286
## 287 2013-11-28 00:00:00    287
## 288 2013-11-29 00:00:00    288
## 289 2013-11-30 00:00:00    289
## 290 2013-12-01 00:00:00    290
## 291 2013-12-02 00:00:00    291
## 292 2013-12-03 00:00:00    292
## 293 2013-12-04 00:00:00    293
## 294 2013-12-05 00:00:00    294
## 295 2013-12-06 00:00:00    295
## 296 2013-12-07 00:00:00    296
## 297 2013-12-08 00:00:00    297
## 298 2013-12-09 00:00:00    298
## 299 2013-12-10 00:00:00    299
## 300 2013-12-11 00:00:00    300
## 301 2013-12-12 00:00:00    301
## 302 2013-12-13 00:00:00    302
## 303 2013-12-14 00:00:00    303
## 304 2013-12-15 00:00:00    304
## 305 2013-12-16 00:00:00    305
## 306 2013-12-17 00:00:00    306
## 307 2013-12-18 00:00:00    307
## 308 2013-12-19 00:00:00    308
## 309 2013-12-20 00:00:00    309
## 310 2013-12-21 00:00:00    310
## 311 2013-12-22 00:00:00    311
## 312 2013-12-23 00:00:00    312
## 313 2013-12-24 00:00:00    313
## 314 2013-12-25 00:00:00    314
## 315 2013-12-26 00:00:00    315
## 316 2013-12-27 00:00:00    316
## 317 2013-12-28 00:00:00    317
## 318 2013-12-29 00:00:00    318
## 319 2013-12-30 00:00:00    319
## 320 2013-12-31 00:00:00    320
## 321 2014-01-01 00:00:00    321
## 322 2014-01-02 00:00:00    322
## 323 2014-01-03 00:00:00    323
## 324 2014-01-04 00:00:00    324
## 325 2014-01-05 00:00:00    325
## 326 2014-01-06 00:00:00    326
## 327 2014-01-07 00:00:00    327
## 328 2014-01-08 00:00:00    328
## 329 2014-01-09 00:00:00    329
## 330 2014-01-10 00:00:00    330
## 331 2014-01-11 00:00:00    331
## 332 2014-01-12 00:00:00    332
## 333 2014-01-13 00:00:00    333
## 334 2014-01-14 00:00:00    334
## 335 2014-01-15 00:00:00    335
## 336 2014-01-16 00:00:00    336
## 337 2014-01-17 00:00:00    337
## 338 2014-01-18 00:00:00    338
## 339 2014-01-19 00:00:00    339
## 340 2014-01-20 00:00:00    340
## 341 2014-01-21 00:00:00    341
## 342 2014-01-22 00:00:00    342
## 343 2014-01-23 00:00:00    343
## 344 2014-01-24 00:00:00    344
## 345 2014-01-25 00:00:00    345
## 346 2014-01-26 00:00:00    346
## 347 2014-01-27 00:00:00    347
## 348 2014-01-28 00:00:00    348
## 349 2014-01-29 00:00:00    349
## 350 2014-01-30 00:00:00    350
## 351 2014-01-31 00:00:00    351
## 352 2014-02-01 00:00:00    352
## 353 2014-02-02 00:00:00    353
## 354 2014-02-03 00:00:00    354
## 355 2014-02-04 00:00:00    355
## 356 2014-02-05 00:00:00    356
## 357 2014-02-06 00:00:00    357
## 358 2014-02-07 00:00:00    358
## 359 2014-02-08 00:00:00    359
## 360 2014-02-09 00:00:00    360
## 361 2014-02-10 00:00:00    361
## 362 2014-02-11 00:00:00    362
## 363 2014-02-12 00:00:00    363
## 364 2014-02-13 00:00:00    364
## 365 2014-02-14 00:00:00    365
## 366 2014-02-15 00:00:00      1
## 367 2014-02-16 00:00:00      2
## 368 2014-02-17 00:00:00      3
## 369 2014-02-18 00:00:00      4
## 370 2014-02-19 00:00:00      5
## 371 2014-02-20 00:00:00      6
## 372 2014-02-21 00:00:00      7
## 373 2014-02-22 00:00:00      8
## 374 2014-02-23 00:00:00      9
## 375 2014-02-24 00:00:00     10
## 376 2014-02-25 00:00:00     11
## 377 2014-02-26 00:00:00     12
## 378 2014-02-27 00:00:00     13
## 379 2014-02-28 00:00:00     14
## 380 2014-03-01 00:00:00     15
## 381 2014-03-02 00:00:00     16
## 382 2014-03-03 00:00:00     17
## 383 2014-03-04 00:00:00     18
## 384 2014-03-05 00:00:00     19
## 385 2014-03-06 00:00:00     20
## 386 2014-03-07 00:00:00     21
## 387 2014-03-08 00:00:00     22
## 388 2014-03-09 00:00:00     23
## 389 2014-03-10 01:00:00     24
## 390 2014-03-11 01:00:00     25
## 391 2014-03-12 01:00:00     26
## 392 2014-03-13 01:00:00     27
## 393 2014-03-14 01:00:00     28
## 394 2014-03-15 01:00:00     29
## 395 2014-03-16 01:00:00     30
## 396 2014-03-17 01:00:00     31
## 397 2014-03-18 01:00:00     32
## 398 2014-03-19 01:00:00     33
## 399 2014-03-20 01:00:00     34
## 400 2014-03-21 01:00:00     35
## 401 2014-03-22 01:00:00     36
## 402 2014-03-23 01:00:00     37
## 403 2014-03-24 01:00:00     38
## 404 2014-03-25 01:00:00     39
## 405 2014-03-26 01:00:00     40
## 406 2014-03-27 01:00:00     41
## 407 2014-03-28 01:00:00     42
## 408 2014-03-29 01:00:00     43
## 409 2014-03-30 01:00:00     44
## 410 2014-03-31 01:00:00     45
## 411 2014-04-01 01:00:00     46
## 412 2014-04-02 01:00:00     47
## 413 2014-04-03 01:00:00     48
## 414 2014-04-04 01:00:00     49
## 415 2014-04-05 01:00:00     50
## 416 2014-04-06 01:00:00     51
## 417 2014-04-07 01:00:00     52
## 418 2014-04-08 01:00:00     53
## 419 2014-04-09 01:00:00     54
## 420 2014-04-10 01:00:00     55
## 421 2014-04-11 01:00:00     56
## 422 2014-04-12 01:00:00     57
## 423 2014-04-13 01:00:00     58
## 424 2014-04-14 01:00:00     59
## 425 2014-04-15 01:00:00     60
## 426 2014-04-16 01:00:00     61
## 427 2014-04-17 01:00:00     62
## 428 2014-04-18 01:00:00     63
## 429 2014-04-19 01:00:00     64
## 430 2014-04-20 01:00:00     65
## 431 2014-04-21 01:00:00     66
## 432 2014-04-22 01:00:00     67
## 433 2014-04-23 01:00:00     68
## 434 2014-04-24 01:00:00     69
## 435 2014-04-25 01:00:00     70
## 436 2014-04-26 01:00:00     71
## 437 2014-04-27 01:00:00     72
## 438 2014-04-28 01:00:00     73
## 439 2014-04-29 01:00:00     74
## 440 2014-04-30 01:00:00     75
## 441 2014-05-01 01:00:00     76
## 442 2014-05-02 01:00:00     77
## 443 2014-05-03 01:00:00     78
## 444 2014-05-04 01:00:00     79
## 445 2014-05-05 01:00:00     80
## 446 2014-05-06 01:00:00     81
## 447 2014-05-07 01:00:00     82
## 448 2014-05-08 01:00:00     83
## 449 2014-05-09 01:00:00     84
## 450 2014-05-10 01:00:00     85
## 451 2014-05-11 01:00:00     86
## 452 2014-05-12 01:00:00     87
## 453 2014-05-13 01:00:00     88
## 454 2014-05-14 01:00:00     89
## 455 2014-05-15 01:00:00     90
## 456 2014-05-16 01:00:00     91
## 457 2014-05-17 01:00:00     92
## 458 2014-05-18 01:00:00     93
## 459 2014-05-19 01:00:00     94
## 460 2014-05-20 01:00:00     95
## 461 2014-05-21 01:00:00     96
## 462 2014-05-22 01:00:00     97
## 463 2014-05-23 01:00:00     98
## 464 2014-05-24 01:00:00     99
## 465 2014-05-25 01:00:00    100
## 466 2014-05-26 01:00:00    101
## 467 2014-05-27 01:00:00    102
## 468 2014-05-28 01:00:00    103
## 469 2014-05-29 01:00:00    104
## 470 2014-05-30 01:00:00    105
## 471 2014-05-31 01:00:00    106
## 472 2014-06-01 01:00:00    107
## 473 2014-06-02 01:00:00    108
## 474 2014-06-03 01:00:00    109
## 475 2014-06-04 01:00:00    110
## 476 2014-06-05 01:00:00    111
## 477 2014-06-06 01:00:00    112
## 478 2014-06-07 01:00:00    113
## 479 2014-06-08 01:00:00    114
## 480 2014-06-09 01:00:00    115
## 481 2014-06-10 01:00:00    116
## 482 2014-06-11 01:00:00    117
## 483 2014-06-12 01:00:00    118
## 484 2014-06-13 01:00:00    119
## 485 2014-06-14 01:00:00    120
## 486 2014-06-15 01:00:00    121
## 487 2014-06-16 01:00:00    122
## 488 2014-06-17 01:00:00    123
## 489 2014-06-18 01:00:00    124
## 490 2014-06-19 01:00:00    125
## 491 2014-06-20 01:00:00    126
## 492 2014-06-21 01:00:00    127
## 493 2014-06-22 01:00:00    128
## 494 2014-06-23 01:00:00    129
## 495 2014-06-24 01:00:00    130
## 496 2014-06-25 01:00:00    131
## 497 2014-06-26 01:00:00    132
## 498 2014-06-27 01:00:00    133
## 499 2014-06-28 01:00:00    134
## 500 2014-06-29 01:00:00    135
## 501 2014-06-30 01:00:00    136
## 502 2014-07-01 01:00:00    137
## 503 2014-07-02 01:00:00    138
## 504 2014-07-03 01:00:00    139
## 505 2014-07-04 01:00:00    140
## 506 2014-07-05 01:00:00    141
## 507 2014-07-06 01:00:00    142
## 508 2014-07-07 01:00:00    143
## 509 2014-07-08 01:00:00    144
## 510 2014-07-09 01:00:00    145
## 511 2014-07-10 01:00:00    146
## 512 2014-07-11 01:00:00    147
## 513 2014-07-12 01:00:00    148
## 514 2014-07-13 01:00:00    149
## 515 2014-07-14 01:00:00    150
## 516 2014-07-15 01:00:00    151
## 517 2014-07-16 01:00:00    152
## 518 2014-07-17 01:00:00    153
## 519 2014-07-18 01:00:00    154
## 520 2014-07-19 01:00:00    155
## 521 2014-07-20 01:00:00    156
## 522 2014-07-21 01:00:00    157
## 523 2014-07-22 01:00:00    158
## 524 2014-07-23 01:00:00    159
## 525 2014-07-24 01:00:00    160
## 526 2014-07-25 01:00:00    161
## 527 2014-07-26 01:00:00    162
## 528 2014-07-27 01:00:00    163
## 529 2014-07-28 01:00:00    164
## 530 2014-07-29 01:00:00    165
## 531 2014-07-30 01:00:00    166
## 532 2014-07-31 01:00:00    167
## 533 2014-08-01 01:00:00    168
## 534 2014-08-02 01:00:00    169
## 535 2014-08-03 01:00:00    170
## 536 2014-08-04 01:00:00    171
## 537 2014-08-05 01:00:00    172
## 538 2014-08-06 01:00:00    173
## 539 2014-08-07 01:00:00    174
## 540 2014-08-08 01:00:00    175
## 541 2014-08-09 01:00:00    176
## 542 2014-08-10 01:00:00    177
## 543 2014-08-11 01:00:00    178
## 544 2014-08-12 01:00:00    179
## 545 2014-08-13 01:00:00    180
## 546 2014-08-14 01:00:00    181
## 547 2014-08-15 01:00:00    182
## 548 2014-08-16 01:00:00    183
## 549 2014-08-17 01:00:00    184
## 550 2014-08-18 01:00:00    185
## 551 2014-08-19 01:00:00    186
## 552 2014-08-20 01:00:00    187
## 553 2014-08-21 01:00:00    188
## 554 2014-08-22 01:00:00    189
## 555 2014-08-23 01:00:00    190
## 556 2014-08-24 01:00:00    191
## 557 2014-08-25 01:00:00    192
## 558 2014-08-26 01:00:00    193
## 559 2014-08-27 01:00:00    194
## 560 2014-08-28 01:00:00    195
## 561 2014-08-29 01:00:00    196
## 562 2014-08-30 01:00:00    197
## 563 2014-08-31 01:00:00    198
## 564 2014-09-01 01:00:00    199
## 565 2014-09-02 01:00:00    200
## 566 2014-09-03 01:00:00    201
## 567 2014-09-04 01:00:00    202
## 568 2014-09-05 01:00:00    203
## 569 2014-09-06 01:00:00    204
## 570 2014-09-07 01:00:00    205
## 571 2014-09-08 01:00:00    206
## 572 2014-09-09 01:00:00    207
## 573 2014-09-10 01:00:00    208
## 574 2014-09-11 01:00:00    209
## 575 2014-09-12 01:00:00    210
## 576 2014-09-13 01:00:00    211
## 577 2014-09-14 01:00:00    212
## 578 2014-09-15 01:00:00    213
## 579 2014-09-16 01:00:00    214
## 580 2014-09-17 01:00:00    215
## 581 2014-09-18 01:00:00    216
## 582 2014-09-19 01:00:00    217
## 583 2014-09-20 01:00:00    218
## 584 2014-09-21 01:00:00    219
## 585 2014-09-22 01:00:00    220
## 586 2014-09-23 01:00:00    221
## 587 2014-09-24 01:00:00    222
## 588 2014-09-25 01:00:00    223
## 589 2014-09-26 01:00:00    224
## 590 2014-09-27 01:00:00    225
## 591 2014-09-28 01:00:00    226
## 592 2014-09-29 01:00:00    227
## 593 2014-09-30 01:00:00    228
## 594 2014-10-01 01:00:00    229
## 595 2014-10-02 01:00:00    230
## 596 2014-10-03 01:00:00    231
## 597 2014-10-04 01:00:00    232
## 598 2014-10-05 01:00:00    233
## 599 2014-10-06 01:00:00    234
## 600 2014-10-07 01:00:00    235
## 601 2014-10-08 01:00:00    236
## 602 2014-10-09 01:00:00    237
## 603 2014-10-10 01:00:00    238
## 604 2014-10-11 01:00:00    239
## 605 2014-10-12 01:00:00    240
## 606 2014-10-13 01:00:00    241
## 607 2014-10-14 01:00:00    242
## 608 2014-10-15 01:00:00    243
## 609 2014-10-16 01:00:00    244
## 610 2014-10-17 01:00:00    245
## 611 2014-10-18 01:00:00    246
## 612 2014-10-19 01:00:00    247
## 613 2014-10-20 01:00:00    248
## 614 2014-10-21 01:00:00    249
## 615 2014-10-22 01:00:00    250
## 616 2014-10-23 01:00:00    251
## 617 2014-10-24 01:00:00    252
## 618 2014-10-25 01:00:00    253
## 619 2014-10-26 01:00:00    254
## 620 2014-10-27 01:00:00    255
## 621 2014-10-28 01:00:00    256
## 622 2014-10-29 01:00:00    257
## 623 2014-10-30 01:00:00    258
## 624 2014-10-31 01:00:00    259
## 625 2014-11-01 01:00:00    260
## 626 2014-11-02 01:00:00    261
## 627 2014-11-03 00:00:00    262
## 628 2014-11-04 00:00:00    263
## 629 2014-11-05 00:00:00    264
## 630 2014-11-06 00:00:00    265
## 631 2014-11-07 00:00:00    266
## 632 2014-11-08 00:00:00    267
## 633 2014-11-09 00:00:00    268
## 634 2014-11-10 00:00:00    269
## 635 2014-11-11 00:00:00    270
## 636 2014-11-12 00:00:00    271
## 637 2014-11-13 00:00:00    272
## 638 2014-11-14 00:00:00    273
## 639 2014-11-15 00:00:00    274
## 640 2014-11-16 00:00:00    275
## 641 2014-11-17 00:00:00    276
## 642 2014-11-18 00:00:00    277
## 643 2014-11-19 00:00:00    278
## 644 2014-11-20 00:00:00    279
## 645 2014-11-21 00:00:00    280
## 646 2014-11-22 00:00:00    281
## 647 2014-11-23 00:00:00    282
## 648 2014-11-24 00:00:00    283
## 649 2014-11-25 00:00:00    284
## 650 2014-11-26 00:00:00    285
## 651 2014-11-27 00:00:00    286
## 652 2014-11-28 00:00:00    287
## 653 2014-11-29 00:00:00    288
## 654 2014-11-30 00:00:00    289
## 655 2014-12-01 00:00:00    290
## 656 2014-12-02 00:00:00    291
## 657 2014-12-03 00:00:00    292
## 658 2014-12-04 00:00:00    293
## 659 2014-12-05 00:00:00    294
## 660 2014-12-06 00:00:00    295
## 661 2014-12-07 00:00:00    296
## 662 2014-12-08 00:00:00    297
## 663 2014-12-09 00:00:00    298
## 664 2014-12-10 00:00:00    299
## 665 2014-12-11 00:00:00    300
## 666 2014-12-12 00:00:00    301
## 667 2014-12-13 00:00:00    302
## 668 2014-12-14 00:00:00    303
## 669 2014-12-15 00:00:00    304
## 670 2014-12-16 00:00:00    305
## 671 2014-12-17 00:00:00    306
## 672 2014-12-18 00:00:00    307
## 673 2014-12-19 00:00:00    308
## 674 2014-12-20 00:00:00    309
## 675 2014-12-21 00:00:00    310
## 676 2014-12-22 00:00:00    311
## 677 2014-12-23 00:00:00    312
## 678 2014-12-24 00:00:00    313
## 679 2014-12-25 00:00:00    314
## 680 2014-12-26 00:00:00    315
## 681 2014-12-27 00:00:00    316
## 682 2014-12-28 00:00:00    317
## 683 2014-12-29 00:00:00    318
## 684 2014-12-30 00:00:00    319
## 685 2014-12-31 00:00:00    320
## 686 2015-01-01 00:00:00    321
## 687 2015-01-02 00:00:00    322
## 688 2015-01-03 00:00:00    323
## 689 2015-01-04 00:00:00    324
## 690 2015-01-05 00:00:00    325
## 691 2015-01-06 00:00:00    326
## 692 2015-01-07 00:00:00    327
## 693 2015-01-08 00:00:00    328
## 694 2015-01-09 00:00:00    329
## 695 2015-01-10 00:00:00    330
## 696 2015-01-11 00:00:00    331
## 697 2015-01-12 00:00:00    332
## 698 2015-01-13 00:00:00    333
## 699 2015-01-14 00:00:00    334
## 700 2015-01-15 00:00:00    335
## 701 2015-01-16 00:00:00    336
## 702 2015-01-17 00:00:00    337
## 703 2015-01-18 00:00:00    338
## 704 2015-01-19 00:00:00    339
## 705 2015-01-20 00:00:00    340
## 706 2015-01-21 00:00:00    341
## 707 2015-01-22 00:00:00    342
## 708 2015-01-23 00:00:00    343
## 709 2015-01-24 00:00:00    344
## 710 2015-01-25 00:00:00    345
## 711 2015-01-26 00:00:00    346
## 712 2015-01-27 00:00:00    347
## 713 2015-01-28 00:00:00    348
## 714 2015-01-29 00:00:00    349
## 715 2015-01-30 00:00:00    350
## 716 2015-01-31 00:00:00    351
## 717 2015-02-01 00:00:00    352
## 718 2015-02-02 00:00:00    353
## 719 2015-02-03 00:00:00    354
## 720 2015-02-04 00:00:00    355
## 721 2015-02-05 00:00:00    356
## 722 2015-02-06 00:00:00    357
## 723 2015-02-07 00:00:00    358
## 724 2015-02-08 00:00:00    359
## 725 2015-02-09 00:00:00    360
## 726 2015-02-10 00:00:00    361
## 727 2015-02-11 00:00:00    362
## 728 2015-02-12 00:00:00    363
## 729 2015-02-13 00:00:00    364
## 730 2015-02-14 00:00:00    365
```

Comment: I have expanded the question if you are still following.  I can also post a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `lubridate` package. This solves almost all timestamp manipulation questions in a straightforward way.

But in this case, you could do something like this:

```
 DF$Julian2 <- DF$Julian %% 365
 DF[DF$Julian2==0, ]$Julian2 <- 365 # changes 0 to 365
```

See `?"%%"` for help.

Comment: I have posted a related question linked here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378708/julian-date-from-set-origin) if you are still following this post.